# Copy constructor of optional using term "direct-non-list-initializes" instead of "copy constructs"

Tags: c++, stdoptional

In C++ standard the copy constructor of optional is defined as follows:

```
constexpr optional(const optional& rhs);

Effects: If rhs contains a value, direct-non-list-initializes the contained value with *rhs.
```

If `rhs` contains a value, it will get copy constructed and [since the copy constructor is defined as deleted unless is_copy_constructible_v is true](https://eel.is/c++draft/optional.ctor#7), why does the standard use the more generic "direct-non-list-initialization" instead of saying `"If rhs contains a value, it 'copy constructs' the contained value with *rhs"`?

Comment: "_copy construct_" is not actually well-defined. You seem to want that it calls the copy constructor, but non-class types do not have one. A class may also have multiple copy constructors, so it isn't well defined which one you mean either. And so on... "_direct-non-list-initialize_" on the other hand is very clear: It behaves as if initializing a variable by `T copy(source);` (rather than `T copy = source;`, `T copy{source};` or `T copy = {source};`)

Answer (score 1):

If `A a`, then both `A a1(a)` and `A a2{a}` are direct-initialized. However, if `A` has an initializer-list constructor, it will always be preferred over other constructors for brace-init-initializers (list initialization). If `A` has both a copy constructor and an initializer-list constructor, the latter is used for `A a2{a}`.

> Effects: If `rhs` contains a value, direct-non-list-initializes the contained value with `*rhs`.

The standard requires that the direct-initializing copy constructor `A(const A&)` is used, and the direct-list-initializing constructor must not be used if a copy constructor is deleted.

Comment: There is no such thing as "direct-copy-initialization". I think you meant "direct-initialization", and that the copy constructor is going to be called.

Comment: I just meant direct initialization with a copy constructor, I did not use any specific terms, otherwise I would make them italic.